# GTM doesn't return the value from array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a customJS variable in GTM. Basically it finds a corresponding value to a key from a dynamic array.

The code I wrote is as follows (for the example I set up an array like this):

```
    function () {
    var items = [{
        finalPrice: 20,
        price: 30,
        productId: "7788",
        quantity: 1,
        sku: "1",
        title: "Apple"
      },
      {
        finalPrice: 10,
        price: 15,
        productId: "5566",
        quantity: 1,
        sku: "2",
        title: "Orange"
      }
    ];
    
    
    return items.find(
  function(i) {
    i.title === "Orange"}).finalPrice;
    
    }
```

What I'd like to get back as the result is the finalPrice of the array item where the title is "Orange", but for some reason I get undefined back, and I can't figure out why. Thank you in advance, I'd greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about GTM. You forgot *return*:

```
return items.find(
  function(i) {
    return i.title === "Orange"
  }).finalPrice;
```